# Using session variables to "authorise" page referrers or remote CFC calls in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I'm just thinking around ideas to try to address form and remote CFC security I wondered about setting a really long/permanent session duration and using

```
if DateDiff("n", now(), session.lastactive) gt 15
```

in onRequest to handle session timeout. Then I could set session.referrer in the referring/calling page and test for it in the form handler or remote cfc. I've not read about it being done , so there's probably good reasons not to do this?

Comment: I don't get it. How does this provide any security? And why would you want to control sessions manually. ColdFusion does it for you already.  I don't see any benefit in this. There are probably already mechanisms for what you are trying to do. Can you be more specific about what that is?

Comment: What I'm trying to prevent is the form handler or remote cfc being accessed from somewhere other than the page on my site which I intend it to be accessed from. I was thinking the variable scope that cant be spoofed are things such as session scope. If the submitting page passes a token and the processing page looks for that would that not stop off site use of the form handler/ajax cfc?

Comment: Jason's answer is the way to go, as it will verify that the request was actually from your own application. You should mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Thought there was a reason I had not heard of this, reason = wheel already invented :-) Saves a lot of time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are describing, I believe, is a feature already built into ColdFusion 8 and higher call verifyClient.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/ajax_security.html

It will create the token when the page is rendered and then verify that the token is sent what te page is submitted. If the token is not sent or is incorrect the call will return a "Client Verification" error.